# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^{1/k}}}{n}$

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I came with the following limit from the Brazilian Math Olympiad:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^{1/k}}}{n}$$

But I couldn't discover any technique to solve it initially, for example, L'Hospital'rule and even I tried seen if it was a taylor series of any known function but I couldn't find also.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome, and here is a *hint*:

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k^{1/k}}$$

Is quite famous - do you know it? Then the Cesaro mean (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation) and [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_Mean)) should help you. Those three links are in no particular order, but the first is more powerful; the second is more directly what you want; the third is a lightweight proof.

Comment: We have to apply Stolz–Cesàro theorem (case $\cdot/\infty)$ twice, do not we? First time, in order to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{k^{1/k}}}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]n}$$ and, second time, in order to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\sqrt[n]n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)=0\;.$$ Is it  right ?

Comment: @Angelo You don’t need Stolz Cesaro at all, but it is a nice general fact. Stolz-Cesaro can be used as you’ve done, your work seems correct to me (except, you should have written $\exp(…)\to\exp(0)=1$, as $n^{1/n}\to1$). However, the last limit can be shown in a variety of different ways. For instance, $\ln x/x\to0$ by L’Hopital’s rule, or by more simple means.

Comment: I wrote the limit with the logarithm function because it is the way to apply Stolz–Cesàro theorem. Of course, since $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\sqrt[n]n\right)=0,\text{ it results that }\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1.\\\text{Anyway, Stolz–Cesàro theorem is necessary to prove that}$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^{1/k}}}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]n}\;\;,$$ is not it?

Comment: @Angelo It is not necessary. But of course it is *nice*, and convenient. However, proving the specific case of Stolz-Cesaro for the Cesaro mean is much easier than proving the general Stolz-Cesaro theorem! That is done in my third link, or on this site before

Comment: Could you tell me how it is possible to calculate the limit of the original poster without using Stolz-Cesàro theorems?

Comment: I've provided a link to such a proof already, so I'll just sketch it here. I know $\frac{1}{k^{1/k}}\to1$ as $k\to\infty$. So for large $k>N$, $\frac{1}{k^{1/k}}\approx1$ and I know: $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^{1/k}}\approx\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k^{1/k}}+\frac{n-N}{n}(1)\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0+1\cdot(1)=1$$The approximation can be tightened arbitrarily well, by pushing $N$ ever larger. So you can show: $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\to\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k$$With the same method, when the limit exists. Stolz-Cesaro theorem is "stronger" than necessary @Angelo

Comment: But, deep inside, you have written the proof of Cesàro mean theorem, so it is equivalent to use that theorem. I just wanted to know if it is possible to calculate the original poster’s limit in another way.

Comment: @Angelo I have written the proof of *Cesaro mean theorem*. **Not** of the Stolz-Cesaro theorem, which is much more general and harder to prove

Comment: It is exactly what I wrote in my last comment.

Comment: @Angelo How did you apply CS theorem?

Comment: @stackexchange Have you looked at the links I showed you? Wikipedia (e.g.) explains how to use Stolz-Cesaro, or the proof wiki page directly gives you your result

Comment: I got it, thank you.

Comment: I just didn't get how the logarithm appeared. Can you explain?

Comment: @stackexchange Because $k^{1/k}=\exp(\ln(k)/k)$, you can figure out the limit of $k^{1/k}$ from the limit of $\ln(k)/k$

Comment: And why $(\ln n)/n = \ln(1+1/n)$?

Comment: @stackexchange $\frac{\ln n}{n}\neq\ln(1+1/n)$. However, one (very overkill!) way to determine $\lim_n\frac{\ln n}{n}$ is to use the Stolz-Cesaro again. If $a_n:=\ln n$ and $b_n:=n$, $a_{n+1}-a_n=\ln(1+1/n)$ and $b_{n+1}-b_n$. So: $$\lim_n\frac{\ln n}{n}=\lim_n\ln(1+1/n)=0$$